# Eclipse is adding full package path when I want to use a class inside jsp files

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, package

My code is quite simple, I'm just trying to do something like this inside my jsp:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
```

And I have this at the top of my jsp file:

```
<%@page language="java" %>
<%@page import="javax.naming.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.rmi.*" %>
<%@page import="ejb.*" %>
```

Problem is that, whenever I use autocomplete and hit enter, eclipse inserts this:

```
javax.naming.Context ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
```

It insists on adding the full class path.
Any ideas how I can avoid this?

Comment: Follow the good practices, don't use scriptlets in your JSPs, and you won't have this problem anymore.

Comment: Well this is for a class, and believe it or not, it's how we're supposed to do it..

Comment: Hmm. Yet another teacher who hasn't learnt anything new for 12 years. I can only feel sorry for you.

Answer (score 1):

The following option should fix your issue (I'm talking about Eclipse Juno (4.2))

`window->Preferences->Editor->Content Assist-> Add import instead of Qualified Name`

Comment: That was already turned on. The Context class is a part of `javax.naming` which is already imported, so it's actually ignoring the import statements for some reason...